# Black edge (NoData pixels) in Landsat 8 color correction in ERDAS

Tags: erdas-imagine, landsat-8, image-mosaic

My boss asked me to mosaic and color-balance multiple Landsat 8 tiles for presentation. I tried to do that in ERDAS but it returned weird result as below:

[image]

Obviously it's the black edges or nodata pixels were counted while balancing the color. Is there a way to eliminate those annoying pixels?

The tiles were exported from the direct 16-bit USGS ".tar.gz" data files into 8-bit images. And the 8-bit images were then brought in to the Mosaic Pro session for color correction. All processes were done by ERDAS. However I also tried to export the 8-bit images through ArcGIS and then process in ERDAS Mosaic Pro but the result was the same.

Comment: Have you tried creating an AOI for each image that can the be added to the mosaicing process? This serves to clip the images to exclude the locals not needed.

Comment: Pixals, not locals.

Comment: Thank you for answering. PROBERT's method worked well - just check "compute active area" when importing image to Mosaic session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number 1: what version are you using ?

Number 2: Don't use the AOI as it is diffcult process to do for more than 2 images.

Number 3: Scroll down to page 18 as it is giving you how to mosaic many images
http://www.gis.usu.edu/~alex/WILD6750/Lab05/Lab05/Lab5_Mosaic_TourGuide.pdf

Comment: It's version 15.

Comment: Thank you! The black edge problem is solved. I think the key step is when import image to the Mosaic session, I should check "compute active area" to eliminate the black edges. Thank you again for this great tutorial.

Comment: @PacmanKX    i am glad to hear that you got your problem solved !