# Merging georeferenced images that have overlapping information?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, envi, geotiff-tiff, image-mosaic

Having trouble to mosaic two overlapping .tif files. I need to merge these two images together into one resampled raster image. Unfortunately I cannot do this with my ability and resource available to me. Notice the image is georeferenced correctly, but it has sections of overlapping data (some with no values). I have tried to use ENVI (georeferenced based mosaic) and ArcGIS (mosaic to new raster) to remove the non data values that overlap good data. What would you do? [image: See images overlayed together here]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have ERDAS, this will work [Black edge (NoData pixels) in Landsat 8 color correction in ERDAS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168922/black-edge-nodata-pixels-in-landsat-8-color-correction-in-erdas/168931#168931)

For ENVI, you should be able to do that. My currently job I don't have here with me but I have use that software in the past with NRCS.  If I remember correctly, there is a wizard that can allow you to use to perform it but since you are not experience with it..  This site should help you out

http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/MosaicAdvancedTutorial.html  or

http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/MosaicSeamless.html

It took me a while to figure it out and understand how this works. Give it a try and do google on it or go to ENVI website.

BTW, I would avoid using ArcGIS and it does not work very well.

Comment: Thank you PROBERT. 

I don't have access to ERDAS but I solved this via ENVI using the Seamless Mosaic tool. The specific field within the tool was "Data value Ignored " which I input the null value (0) from my dataset. 

Thank you very much

Comment: @zemeken  I am glad it works out for you. I seem to like ENVI more than ERDAS but if you must do a lot of imagery  then ERDAS has a nice tool AutoSync. Very nice toolbox.

Answer (score 2):

It depends it your image has nodata (or null) value set up correctly. If you look at the image properties in ArcMap, in the Source tab a NoData Value should be defined. If your NoData Value is not defined, try the "set null" command, where you can have cells converted to null acording to some query rule. But be aware that this tool will be applied to the entire image so cells with value 0 (zero) in the middle of the image can be converted to null.

Another option, which I think is best, is to use the tools "Copy Raster" and set the proper "Ignore Background value". This way the image border is set to NoData.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this via **ENVI** using the **Seamless Mosaic tool**. The specific field within the tool was "**Data Value Ignored**" which I input the **null value** (0) from my dataset.