# Landsat 8 mosaic

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, landsat-8

When I tried to mosaic two Landsat-8 images in ArcGIS 10.4, I found overlaps area after mosaic and it appears as sharp line and it looks like two images with different colors. I want to make them as one image without any line or contact in between.

---

What I'm asking like in the figure, I dont want to see this edge after mosaic in ArcGIS :[image: mosaic]

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Is that what you are looking for ?
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168922/black-edge-nodata-pixels-in-landsat-8-color-correction-in-erdas/168931#168931

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the tour to learn about our focused Question and Answer format. There is an [Edit] link below your question that will allow you to edit your question and add extra info.

Comment: Any update???????

Comment: You are looking for something call "[color balancing](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=color+balancing+landsat+8+arcgis)"